# How to change subfloat caption label name?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, subfig

The `\autoref` command is not giving me a "Figure" label name for subfigures made inside subfloats. There are answers how to control the label numbering but the label name I was not lucky to find an answer to that. I am doing a workaround identifying a `\newcommand` at the preamble as shown in the following MWE, but I love to see more control over the hyperref/subfig packages behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}

%Command to add Figure word to the autoref command
\newcommand\sfigautoref[1]{Figure~\autoref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics{figa}
    %\caption{atest}
    \label{a}
}
  \subfloat[]{

    \includegraphics{figb}
    %\caption{btest}
    \label{b}
}
\end{figure}

Now this \sfigautoref{a} works, although the link is just on the number a direct use of \texttt{\textbackslash autoref\{text\}} use with controlled behaviour is preferred.
Thanks all in advance,

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

See page 18 of the hyperref manual.  Note that `\subfigurename` is also used by `\subfloat` (bad).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\let\subfigureautorefname=\figurename

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[\label{a}]{
    \includegraphics{figa}
}
  \subfloat[\label{b}]{
    \includegraphics{figb}
}
\end{figure}

Now this \autoref{a} works as expected.
\end{document}
```